# SQL statement should return 2 rows but returns only one

Tags: java, android, sqlite

The `Account` table contains 2 rows when the query is executed it returns only one row.
when the database is opened in SQLite(Software to view sql database on pc) it shows 2 proper rows.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> returnAccount(Context context)
{
    HashMap<String,Integer> account = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    try
    {
        // Query in question
        String statement = "SELECT * FROM `Account`;";

        c = mydatabase.rawQuery(statement,null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                Log.e("Count", String.valueOf(c.getCount()));
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
}
```

I tried deleting the entire table and rechecked the all the queries but nothing helped.
I expected all (2) rows.
2019-07-12 18:06:06.780 5663-5663/com.prasad.budgetmanager E/Count: 1
This are the logged data.

Entire Code is at https://github.com/prasad610/BugetManager/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/prasad/budgetmanager/ExtraFunctions.java

[Actual database content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dyha.png)

Comment: If getCount() returns 1 then there is only 1 row in the table, so as you say when you open the database in a program to see its contents and you see 2 rows then you have another database and not a copy of the device's database.

Comment: at your second `Log` in the `do` scope you write `c.moveToNext()` inside `valueOf` so it will skip second row.

Comment: @forpas I recreated the database and then saved it from device file explorer from android studio. It still shows more than one row with the ones i newly entered.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line.
//Log.e("Move to next", String.valueOf(c.moveToNext()));

The c.moveToNext() is already moved the cursor to Next value. so the while loop will return false  it will not execute the next value.

Comment: Although what you say is correct, since `getCount()` returns `1` it means that there is **only 1 row**.

Comment: It didn't work the count is still 1 even after removing that line.

Comment: Also, using DatabaseUtils to check the cursor it shows all rows its when it enters do while it returns one.